# Openssl: cannot validate client certificate issued by Root CA certificate

Tags: openssl

Im sorry for raising yet another Openssl topic, but here's an issue I can't really solve.

I have an app, that connects to server (an a form of another app) which is in the same network.
SSL certificate is needed for this connection.

Server accepts self-signed certificate created this way:

`openssl genrsa -out privkey.pem 4096`

`openssl req -x509 -config certconfig.txt -new -nodes -key privkey.pem -days 3650 -out newcert.pem`

`openssl pkcs12 -inkey privkey.pem -in newcert.pem -export -out newcert.pfx -passout pass:`

certconfig.txt assigns the only Common Name that is accepted by server, and this is correct according to specification.

Self-signed cert is accepted by the server, but security requirements changed and now only Root CA - signed certificates are to be accepted. And here a problem stars:

**I create Root CA certificate and client certificate.**

Root CA certificate:
`openssl genrsa -out rootca.pem 4096`

`openssl req -x509 -new -nodes -key rootca.pem -days 3650 -config certconfig_root.txt -out rootca.crt`

Client app key:
`openssl genrsa -out privkey.pem 4096`

Client app cert sign reques (certconfig_client has a proper Common Name inside):
`openssl req -new -key privkey.pem -config certconfig_client.txt -out newcert.csr`

Client app cert:
`openssl x509 -req -in newcert.csr -CA rootca.crt -CAkey rootca.pem -CAcreateserial -out newcert.pem -days 3650`

Client app cert -> *.pfx
`openssl pkcs12 -inkey privkey.pem -in newcert.pem -export -out newcert.pfx -passout pass:`

Root CA cert -> *.pfx
`openssl pkcs12 -inkey rootca.pem -in rootca.crt -export -out rootca.pfx -passout pass:`

**I move client certificate to the app, and **install Root CA certificate in Windows, in Trusted Root Certification Authorities**.**

Now, actual problem:

When I try to connect with this client app cert newcert.pfx, server closes connection due to SSL handshake failed. App returns an exception:

```
{"The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted"}
```

When I try to debug this connection via OpenSSL command:

```
s_client -connect {server_address) -showcerts
```

it shows that:

> Verify return code: 21 (unable to verify the first certificate)

If I dobug it with specifying Root CA cert file via

```
s_client -connect {server_address) -showcerts -CAfile {Root CA cert location}
```

if actually sees the cert chain but returns error:

> verify return:1 13728:error:14094410:SSLroutines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3
> alert handshake failure:ssl\record\rec_layer_s3.c:1544:SSL alert
> number 40

**It seems that when my app connects to server, somehow it's cert does not have a "link" to Root CA cert, which is installed on this machine.**

Now the big question is: why?

Comment: Have you ever been found answer to this?

Comment: Yes I was my bad, I created certificates wrong way. I remember that I had to create one based on another, instead the way I did. But I was long time ago and I can't help you with details